# Only takes the first data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 table rows with different data-id="" and I want jQuery to append that id to a paragraph. So my HTML is like this:

```
<tr>
<td id="pmd" data-id="123">First cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="pmd" data-id="456">Second cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="pmd" data-id="789">Third cell</td>
</tr>

<p id="tp"></p>
```

And my jQuery is like this:

```
$('#pmd').click(function(event) {
     var po = $(this).data('id');
     $("#tp").append(po);
});
```

But this jQuery code only takes the first table's cell data-id and not the second and the third row's data ids.

Of course this is only a part of my code, because I need to use this to $_POST using PHP

Thanks

Comment: ID's should be unique.

Comment: ...use class instead, or just target td's.

Comment: But PHP generates the table automatically by getting data from the SQL database, I can't make them unique.

Comment: Oh wait, you are right, I totally forgot about classes. Let me try it

Comment: @xPersonx, you must... also, if you need ids, for some reason, you can increment it in loop: pmd1,pmd2...

Comment: If the table has an id (or it is the only table on the page) then you could use CSS selectors to reference particular cells without having to give every cell a class-name.

Comment: The PHP should also be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using same id is rule violation. Don't do that. Use class instead of id.

```js
$('.pmd').click(function(event) {
     var po = $(this).data('id');
     $("#tp").append(po);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table>
   <tr>
      <td class="pmd" data-id="123">First cell</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="pmd" data-id="456">Second cell</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="pmd" data-id="789">Third cell</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<p id="tp"></p>
```

If you don't want to change your html click td instead of id.But same id is bad practice. I don't recommended it.

```js
$('td').click(function(event) {
     var po = $(this).data('id');
     $("#tp").append(po);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table>
   <tr>
      <td class="pmd" data-id="123">First cell</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="pmd" data-id="456">Second cell</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="pmd" data-id="789">Third cell</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<p id="tp"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate ids in your code. Due to which, `$('#pmd')` selector selects first element with id pmd. IDs must be unique. What you can do is

1) You can rather use common class(say pmd) and then use class selector to attach the event:

```
$('.pmd').click(function(event) {
   var po = $(this).data('id');
   $("#tp").append(po);
});
```

2) Find td elements with attribute data id in table and attach the event to them:

```
$('table td[data-id]').click(function(event) {
   var po = $(this).data('id');
   $("#tp").append(po);
});
```